# How to dynamic change the domain of a Many2one field in ODOO

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, many-to-one

I want to dynamic change the domain of many2one field every time the value of dul changes #dul is Boolean

in the first case so that `domain="[('parent_id', '!=', False), ('parent_id', '=', imeReona)]"` ,
and in another case `domain="[('parent_id', '!=', False)]"`

I tried:

`my_many2one_field = fields.Many2one(..., domain=lambda self: self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('domen_mm2o'))`

`@api.onchange('dul')
    def _onchange_dul(self):
        if (self.dul == True):
            res = "[('parent_id','!=',False),('parent_id','=',imeReona)]"
        else:
            res = "[('parent_id','!=',False)]"
        self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param('domen_mm2o',res)`

If I was not clear enough or did not formulate the question well, please let me know

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: @Navi if still not clear enough, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the code.
From `my_many2one_field` I removed `, domain=lambda self: self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('domen_mm2o')`

and updated

```
@api.onchange('dul')
def _onchange_dul(self):
    if (self.dul == True):
        res = "[('parent_id','!=',False),('parent_id','=',imeReona)]"
    else:
        res = "[('parent_id','!=',False)]"
    self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param('domen_mm2o',res)
```

## added the following code

```
    return{
        'domain': {'my_many2one_field': self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('domen_mm2o')}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@api.onchange('partner_id')
def apply_domain_customer(self):
    vehicles = self.env['fleet.vehicle'].search([('driver_id', '=', 
      self.partner_id.id)]).ids
    return {
        'domain': {
            'vehicle': [('id', 'in', vehicles)]
        }}
```

Comment: I think dynamic domain can do your work like this code

Comment: Thank you very much @Akshay , your answer helped me fix my code